# Windows 2008 DNS and BIND views

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, bind

Good afternoon!
I'm trying to find a definitive answer to whether I can accomplish a management directive for DNS infrastructure.

In a Windows 2008 R2 environment, is it possible to have DNS "views" as we can in BIND9?  Can we have one DNS zone split into two scopes and replicate one of those scopes to a BIND9 Linux server in the DMZ? Any possibility of doing this in Windows 2012 R2?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot with the MS DNS server.

Comment: But you could always run BIND under Windows.  There are installable packages for this.

Comment: Now, the next question: since DNS does not "advertise" the service in the way that DHCP, for example, "advertises", one solution might be to install DNS on a lightly-used Windows server in the intranet, statically configure the zone files with ONLY the external addresses required, and replicate to BIND slave servers in the DMZ.  So long as no other host looks to the new Windows DNS server and replications are locked down to the specific BIND servers in the DMZ, there should be no leakage between the internal and external views. Any thoughts on whether I've missed any crucial concepts?